# Silverlight DataGrid to work like Excel

Tags: silverlight, excel, datagrid

In using the Silverlight DataGrid and I wanted it to work like Excel, I assume the best way

if I was not using a DomainDataSource was to and was just binding the itemsource to an observablecollection,

what would be the best way to add a new row...Should I just temporarily add an item to the observablecollection?

Would there be a way to move to that row and place it in edit mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datagrid does not support movable rows, so you'll have to implement it by yourself.

Have a look on the following project:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/DataGridWithMovableRow.aspx

You can either use it as is, or use its logic to build something that best suites you.